# Instantiate with different classes?

Tags: c#

This might sound dump, but can I do such thing:

```
public class CameraConnection
{
    Object camera;
    public CameraConnection(bool isNewCamera)
    {
        if(isNewCamera)
        {
            camera = new Camera1();
            
        }
        else
        {
            camera = new Camera2();
        }
    }
    public void TakeImage()
    {
        camera.TakeImage();
    }
}
```

So here I can call camera.TakeImage() for taking an image, but base on which class the variable camera is instantiated (Camera1 or Camera2) it actually uses differrent camera APIs..

I feel like this is somewhat related to class abstraction or interface but not really sure...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you should have a base class and use that instead of 'object'

Comment: `dynamic camera;`

Comment: if you end up using the ICamera solution (you marked it as correct so I assume so) and you find yourself repeating stuff between both classes then that means you need base / derived structure like in the other answer, common code goes in the base, the differences in the derived classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

define an interface the defines the behavior of a camera.

```
public interface ICamera{
  void TakeImage();
  int HowManyPicsInCamera();
  .....
  // all the things a camera object needs to do
}
```

now have some classses that implement it

```
public class Camera1:ICamera{
    void TakeImage(){
    }
     int HowManyPicsInCamera(){
    }
}


public class Camera2:ICamera{
    void TakeImage(){
    }
     int HowManyPicsInCamera(){
    }
}
```

now use that

```
public class CameraConnection
{
    ICamera camera;
    public CameraConnection(bool isNewCamera)
    {
        if(isNewCamera)
        {
            camera = new Camera1();
            
        }
        else
        {
            camera = new Camera2();
        }
    }
    public void TakeImage()
    {
        camera.TakeImage();
    }
}
```

alternatively you can use a base class, you do that if there is common implementation details. Like common data or code.

Comment: @CaiusJard well the OP ticked it as accepted so I guess not confused, but I will fix

Comment: Yep, though don't forget that answers aren't just for the OP.. the next visitor might not get the point being made ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is related to class abstraction, inheritance to be exact.

For example:

```cs
public class BaseCamera {}

public class Camera1 : BaseCamera {}

public class Camera2 : BaseCamera {}
```

This will then allow you to instantiate multiple camera types based on the parent class. I recommend nuking `object` as the type because the compiler won't be able to resolve `camera.TakeImage()` for example.